# Unity / Vuforia to Xcode - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Unity 2019.2.1f1
Xcode

Please help I have spent days trying to fix this with no luck :(

I am trying to build to IOS using Unity > Xcode. 
The unity project uses the latest vuforia package 8.3.9

I get the following errors in xcode.... there are 68 undefined symbol: errors. They all seem to do with Vuforia.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_EnumerateVideoFormats", referenced from:
      _UnityARVideoFormat_EnumerateVideoFormats_mA35382A4D798A5D86D66252230E9D344870125BE in Assembly-CSharp9.o
      _UnityARVideoFormat_SupportedVideoFormats_mD96A9FE18011B092EE478643DF9243316F1D51AA in Assembly-CSharp9.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARVideoFormat_EnumerateVideoFormats_mA35382A4D798A5D86D66252230E9D344870125BE)
  "_session_ExtractReferenceObject", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_ExtractReferenceObject_mFCDF359360EFD1A44FC8C5AE091D8AF475FFA27E in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_ExtractReferenceObjectAsync_m96752451EA0769F65FF629833E826CEE9E3B080E in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_ExtractReferenceObject_mFCDF359360EFD1A44FC8C5AE091D8AF475FFA27E)
  "_Native_IsARKit_1_5_Supported", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_Native_IsARKit_1_5_Supported_m8EDF4E21A68C45FD540E644B9A7BF54864D104C8 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_IsARKit_1_5_Supported_m9CFC1B6B25472E6B1104FE3E1F085C452C122FAC in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_Native_IsARKit_1_5_Supported_m8EDF4E21A68C45FD540E644B9A7BF54864D104C8)
  "_SessionSetWorldOrigin", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionSetWorldOrigin_m8F6DAFC26FEB167BA189600264811FCB77DFFA71 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetWorldOrigin_m85DD5AF46AEA9C89EDDFBE03B5BC75F3588D86A1 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionSetWorldOrigin_m8F6DAFC26FEB167BA189600264811FCB77DFFA71)
  "_CapturePixelData", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_CapturePixelData_mB5D95348F0F9D895F8B30C336BB87B5371F45711 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCapturePixelData_m520AC4F19B2435D8932006C916F8454887690A31 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_CapturePixelData_mB5D95348F0F9D895F8B30C336BB87B5371F45711)
  "_SetCameraNearFar", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCameraNearFar_m300A89711AE2D3F3F97B14689D8D968064440EC3 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCameraClipPlanes_m54CDF57CD70D9714102929B87AAE4E7D002AC3CE in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SetCameraNearFar_m300A89711AE2D3F3F97B14689D8D968064440EC3)
  "_GetAmbientIntensity", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetAmbientIntensity_mE42C6620DED241FAE2718E809DB3728A42FA50AA in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetARAmbientIntensity_m48B094353D0E72CA9A1E0F1CAC66E31E8FB2BD65 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetAmbientIntensity_mE42C6620DED241FAE2718E809DB3728A42FA50AA)
  "_HitTest", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_m7D7351903A27A634A48635E33D5FECA8E65CE483 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_m95F6475516CBB079F90CF38D467CA8809D89B670 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: GUILayer_CUSTOM_HitTest_Injected(ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*, Vector2f const&), GUIElement_CUSTOM_HitTest_Injected(ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*, Vector2f const&, RectT<float> const&) , _UnityARHitTestBarb_HitTestWithResultType_mD4873B6BE4BE7F870E936967C81229A3407F9BA4_MetadataUsageId , _UnityARHitTestExample_HitTestWithResultType_m0D2E90D8D38A47AE819F040A37156DEC894D0297 , _SmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mD2E06317631EA56722F9383C049AC91C7BFFDAB9 , _HitTestResult_GetHashCode_mA742731A9B8E88524E2AA894FD42C07A4449D3A8 , _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_m95F6475516CBB079F90CF38D467CA8809D89B670_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_1_0_2 , _HitTestResult_ToString_m3E6F6768C2C2D6937F50DD4A5EBDE1AE51C26A43_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestMode_tA27F6512F1F271CA16946F6B0D654F766469973B_0_0_32854 , _PlaymodeSmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mBF1D8AF51AB80E26B5D39E8C44AB8177FA27CA9A , _HitTestResult_Equals_mA9D06940ADDB0D8EF682D6AD6D47E04E6A4332B7 , _HitTestResult__ctor_m3DFDEE13F482351123783E358D5A77A0AA1423FB , _HitTestResult_get_Rotation_m51089686BA4D09998DA3BB46FE13F13B4B1EF483 , _HitTestResult_get_Position_m7262B7678918D42072CD9AE5D9192007420D8A80 , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_com_cleanup , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_com_back , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_com , _GUILayer_HitTest_Injected_m7CE3813363D0141DB2112C83C1E958189CBB6609 , Register_UnityEngine_GUILayer_HitTest_Injected() , _GUILayer_HitTest_mD44413399C4E2DE830CBF4BECBE42BA2AB8FE350 , _HitTestResult_get_HitTestPtr_mF2A543A70D585AA3E0C917C0165714AE791C0CF9 , _HitTestEvent_t63AB9C2D85E4DB67BA4AEF13B8E65862E90FED4F_0_0_0 , _HitTestMode_tA27F6512F1F271CA16946F6B0D654F766469973B_0_0_0 , _HitTestEvent_t63AB9C2D85E4DB67BA4AEF13B8E65862E90FED4F_0_0_6 , _HitTestMode_tA27F6512F1F271CA16946F6B0D654F766469973B_0_0_1 , _HitTestResultU5BU5D_t4B72241395D4BA4D40872ACF57262DAD640F66B0_1_0_2 , _SendMouseEvents_HitTestLegacyGUI_m113417860754D02D1E14BC2F332D0C7206BD8C05 , _HitTestResult_Equals_mAE7EC85AA27352CB1804387B6C4320D25C3EA39D , _SmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mD2E06317631EA56722F9383C049AC91C7BFFDAB9_MetadataUsageId , _SendMouseEvents_HitTestLegacyGUI_m113417860754D02D1E14BC2F332D0C7206BD8C05_MetadataUsageId , _PlaymodeSmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_m8B87C0A2CF497B0575A68CE2028060E2960CEE97_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResult_Equals_mAE7EC85AA27352CB1804387B6C4320D25C3EA39D_MetadataUsageId , _UnityARHitTestExamplePortal_HitTestWithResultType_m67D4729CD94157A07324D11A0558AFDD208854B9_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_0_0_0_var , _HitTestEvent__ctor_m11E94285A92FABC41F6DF8D5EB17035A1B64A87C_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_m7D7351903A27A634A48635E33D5FECA8E65CE483 , _PlaymodeSmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_m8B87C0A2CF497B0575A68CE2028060E2960CEE97 , _HitTestResultU5BU5D_t4B72241395D4BA4D40872ACF57262DAD640F66B0_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_0_0_0 , _PlaymodeSmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mBF1D8AF51AB80E26B5D39E8C44AB8177FA27CA9A_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_pinvoke , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_pinvoke_back , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_marshal_pinvoke_cleanup , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_1_0_0 , _GenInst_HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_0_0_0 , _HitTestEvent_t63AB9C2D85E4DB67BA4AEF13B8E65862E90FED4F_1_0_0 , _HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_0_0_6 , _HitTestResult_Equals_mA9D06940ADDB0D8EF682D6AD6D47E04E6A4332B7_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResultU5BU5D_t4B72241395D4BA4D40872ACF57262DAD640F66B0_0_0_0 , _GUILayer_HitTest_m8C36C21249CBDA2579E84608932F6EBF015D953D , Register_UnityEngine_GUIElement_HitTest_Injected() , _SmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mF8F9791AC60DC5D0E2E402A0E1A926D7CC514761_MetadataUsageId , _FocusSquare_HitTestWithResultType_m605F8C7334FC299A8C6047B524DB68F19A13373B , _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_m95F6475516CBB079F90CF38D467CA8809D89B670 , _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_mC500A647AADD73F624C7CE3F71BD70833A7B4837 , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_0_0_0 , _FocusSquare_HitTestWithResultType_m605F8C7334FC299A8C6047B524DB68F19A13373B_MetadataUsageId , _UnityARHitTestBarb_HitTestWithResultType_mD4873B6BE4BE7F870E936967C81229A3407F9BA4 , _HitCreateEnvironmentProbe_HitTestWithResultType_m5B78F13D2BA8B70FB5207569E66281E698E5C89B , _SmartTerrainImpl_HitTest_mF8F9791AC60DC5D0E2E402A0E1A926D7CC514761 , _HitTestResult_t53FC02E2A830035AD9ED88C46D9975FD1B5C59DE_1_0_0 , _UnityARHitTestExamplePortal_HitTestWithResultType_m67D4729CD94157A07324D11A0558AFDD208854B9 , _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_HitTest_mC500A647AADD73F624C7CE3F71BD70833A7B4837_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResult_ToString_m3E6F6768C2C2D6937F50DD4A5EBDE1AE51C26A43 , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_pinvoke_FromNativeMethodDefinition_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3_com_FromNativeMethodDefinition_MetadataUsageId , _PlaneFinderBehaviour_get_HitTestMode_m58D54A68EE6E644AB03D42539E2B714C43A513BA , _PlaneFinderBehaviour_set_HitTestMode_m56403B67A7B955700E0483AC5D963ED4733E724E , _HitCreateEnvironmentProbe_HitTestWithResultType_m5B78F13D2BA8B70FB5207569E66281E698E5C89B_MetadataUsageId , _UnityARHitTestExample_HitTestWithResultType_m0D2E90D8D38A47AE819F040A37156DEC894D0297_MetadataUsageId , _HitTestMode_tA27F6512F1F271CA16946F6B0D654F766469973B_1_0_0 , RuntimeInvoker_FalseRuntimeObject_HitTestResultData_t67DDE76CFB43E7C2EF3EA7CA447F2F66C0201FE3(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) , _HitTestEvent__ctor_m11E94285A92FABC41F6DF8D5EB17035A1B64A87C )
  "_StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions_m72BDAF7253FD70011C6C6EAF0FD6481215B5460D in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions_m72BDAF7253FD70011C6C6EAF0FD6481215B5460D)
  "_StartFaceTrackingSession", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSession_mAF0B430D694EBB7E3369EEBC6D1C232922865033 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSession_mAF0B430D694EBB7E3369EEBC6D1C232922865033, _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartFaceTrackingSessionWithOptions_m72BDAF7253FD70011C6C6EAF0FD6481215B5460D )
  "_StartSessionWithOptions", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSessionWithOptions_m468A75438913905FDF44A75D6995881F18088DC2 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_RunWithConfigAndOptions_mBBED22D7522A640D35AF705CE857C9363045BE3F in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartSessionWithOptions_m468A75438913905FDF44A75D6995881F18088DC2)
  "_StartWorldTrackingSession", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSession_mCC27A1E2D4DDA42120C0BE3D6FDF5DE5FCBF997A in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSession_mCC27A1E2D4DDA42120C0BE3D6FDF5DE5FCBF997A, _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mE0440B192425A3593D7E4461EBF4537494C63CE7 )
  "_session_GetARKitSessionPtr", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_GetARKitSessionPtr_m5146A968D9E3CB7843A85661C9126A03A57F766A in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_GetNativeSessionPtr_m46F1029321E8C9D6D6D31855DB529A5CD0A9CE21 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_GetARKitSessionPtr_m5146A968D9E3CB7843A85661C9126A03A57F766A)
  "_session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks_m5CE4D9A6B9B87734231FDCA367B160377859D3DC in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_session_SetPlaneAnchorCallbacks_m5CE4D9A6B9B87734231FDCA367B160377859D3DC)
  "_SessionAddUserAnchor", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionAddUserAnchor_m99EACE0AFE3101DBB8B4A97CEF33CC0150EBF91B in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_AddUserAnchor_m4855970A3A64D205BE24D309405236C3143D868D in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_SessionAddUserAnchor_m99EACE0AFE3101DBB8B4A97CEF33CC0150EBF91B)
  "_Native_IsARKit_2_0_Supported", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_IsARKit_2_0_Supported_m57AC715727875E6D8C9FEF6B89C48F4C0CF710CE in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_Native_IsARKit_2_0_Supported_m739218316F28D25AC598B04C6488ECFC0270A7E3 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_Native_IsARKit_2_0_Supported_m739218316F28D25AC598B04C6488ECFC0270A7E3)
  "_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mE0440B192425A3593D7E4461EBF4537494C63CE7 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_StartWorldTrackingSessionWithOptions_mE0440B192425A3593D7E4461EBF4537494C63CE7)
  "_worldMap_GetExtent", referenced from:
      _ARWorldMap_get_extent_mDA5CEA8C24C66341C9F554D366475CE6A6290118 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
      _ARWorldMap_worldMap_GetExtent_mDB403809F22D230138268ADA5147AD24584DCD8F in Assembly-CSharp8.o
     (maybe you meant: _ARWorldMap_worldMap_GetExtent_mDB403809F22D230138268ADA5147AD24584DCD8F)
  "_referenceObjectsSet_AddReferenceObject", referenced from:
      _UnityARSessionNativeInterface_CreateNativeReferenceObjectsSet_m788018F208A05E39FAC4BB46EA0991A132502334 in Assembly-CSharp8.o
```

I have tried...

1. Removing Vuforia, re-adding.
2. Creating a new project, importing `vuforia` sample from the asset store which does build. I then imported my assets from the original project but when trying to build I get the same error as above...[Screenshot of error in xcode][[image: Error Image from XCode [1]]

Comment: Please add the Unity, macOS and Xcode versions.

Comment: Hei, Andrew, did you solve your problem? I have the same type of problem, but with the AdMob.